# When saving a editable text block in HTML it deletes the whole page except for the text you typed

Tags: javascript, html

The whole server side thing works. And it does save but the thing is it just wipes everything when you save.. so I want it to stay inside the text block and not delete everything. I am a beginner so it is kind of hard for me to fix this.

This is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Suggesties</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Edit and Save Text</h1>

    <textarea id="editText" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button onclick="saveText()">Save</button>

    <div id="savedTextContainer"></div>

    <script>
        function saveText() {
            const editedText = document.getElementById("editText").value;

            fetch("http://myip:3000/save", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ text: editedText }),
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    if (data.success) {
                        const savedTextContainer = document.getElementById("savedTextContainer");
                        savedTextContainer.innerHTML += `<p>${editedText}</p>`;
                        // Optionally, clear the textarea after saving
                        document.getElementById("editText").value = "";
                    } else {
                        console.error("Failed to save text:", data.message);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error("Error saving text:", error);
                });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried a lot of things and different functions etc.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what you're telling it do here:

```
    ...
    if (data.success) {
        const savedTextContainer = document.getElementById("savedTextContainer");
        savedTextContainer.innerHTML += `<p>${editedText}</p>`;
        // Optionally, clear the textarea after saving
        document.getElementById("editText").value = "";
    ...
    }
```

With this approach I suspect you would need to grab the whole page's contents, replace the element (only) and send the whole document once the replacement is complete.